# java spring3 annotation basec controller with logging

Tags: spring, aop

I am using java with spring3 i have following controller's service method

```
@Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    }
```

I have the following method which performs logging for every method, i want to call this method for every service method

```
public void performLog(HttpServletRequest request){
//process params and log msg
log.debug()
}
```

Please tell me how can i call performLog(request) method after service method automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use Spring AOP for it . Use an @Before annotation specifying the necessary pointcut . Place this method in a class annotated with @Aspect . Something similar to

```
@Aspect
public class BeforeExample {

  @Pointcut("execution(ModelAndView com.xyz.myapp.MyController.handleRequest(..))")
  public void performLog() {
  // ...
  }

  @Before("execution(* com.xyz.myapp.MyController.*(..))")
  public void performLogAll() {
  // ...
  }
}
```

Pointcut samples can be found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples)

Check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj) for more info